# Akka-http merge incoming connections

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm trying to use akka-streams and akka-http in order to solve the following problem:

- we have 2 http clients (A and B) sending requests to 1 http server (C). Both side use akka-http to communicate.
- requests from A have higher priority compared to B, but both requests should be processes equally. So C should first process requests from A, requests from B are of second priority
- of course we would like to have back-pressure on each end enabled

I come up with the following code in order to get incoming connections merged to one output:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(FlowGraph.create() { implicit b: FlowGraph.Builder[Unit] =>
    import FlowGraph.Implicits._

    val merge = b.add(MergePreferred[IncomingConnection](1))

    val inA: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] = Http().bind(interface = "localhost", port = 8200)
    val inB: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] = Http().bind(interface = "localhost", port = 8201)

    inA ~> merge.preferred
    inB ~> merge.in(0)
           merge.out ~> Sink.foreach(println)

    ClosedShape
}).run()
```

So, I have a Source with IncomingConnection inctances from A and B.

Now I want to process them somehow, produce responses and send responses to corresponding connections.

Maybe there are better ways to archive all these things but I could not find any example solving such problem in docs or questions from other people.

Also I guess the problem is quite common.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `IncomingConnection` objects are used to process requests and return responses is with the `handleXXX` methods.  Examples based on the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/snapshot/scala/http/low-level-server-side-api.html#Request-Response_Cycle) and the [api](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M2/?_ga=1.151623801.1917589872.1429296441#akka.http.javadsl.IncomingConnection):

**Synchronous Function**

```
//this processor contains your logic for converting a request into a response
def requestProcessor(httpRequest : HttpRequest) : HttpResponse = ???

val connectionSink = Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection] { conn =>
  conn.handleWithSyncHandler(requestProcessor)
}
```

This `connectionSink` can then be used in your graph construct:

```
inA ~> merge.preferred
inB ~> merge.in(0)
       merge.out ~> connectionSink
```

**Asynchronous Function**

Similarly, if your processor is asynchronous:

```
val asyncReqProcessor(httpRequest : HttpRequest) : Future[HttpResponse] = ???

val connectionSink = 
  Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection](_ handleWithAsyncHandler asyncProcessor)
```

**Flow**

And finally, you can also use a Flow (my preferred method):

```
val flowReqProcessor : Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse,_] = ???

val connectionSink = 
  Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection](_ handleWith flowReqProcessor )
```

One of my favorite features about Flows is that you can re-use them over & over in different Streams.  Therefore, flowReqProcessor can be a `val` instead of a `def`.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed. Would be great to update documentation with more examples on handling connections...

Comment: @d-n-ust You are welcome.  I agree the docs are a bit lacking at times.  akka-streams was promoted out of "experimental" just this past July so it is still young.  In the past few months I think I've seen the reference docs double in size (slowly but surely).   Happy hacking!

Comment: The solution actually does not solve my problem - I need to prioritize requests, not connections (started another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315419/how-to-convert-sourceincomingconnection-to-sourcehttprequest)